# Square Grid Edge Weight Storage in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, grid

Consider a usual square grid in two dimensions. Between adjacent grid points I need to store a number. Essentially, I'm storing edge weights. What is the best way to do this, say in MATLAB so that if I call up a grid point, it will produce the weights of adjacent edges. The edges are undirected so for example, the upper edge at (0,0) has the same value as the lower edge at (0,1). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value to a matrix and then get the top value with ceil(index+0.5) and bottom value with floor(index+0.5)

eg to find the value between rows 3 and 4 :

top of cell 3 would be ceil(3+0.5)=ceil(3.5)=4.
bottom of cell 4 would be floor(4+0.5)=floor(4.5)=4

you are probably best writing two functions like

```
function value=topval(index)
    ceil(index+0.5);
end

function value=botval(index)
    floor(index+0.5);
end
```

If you want the left/right border values you can write similar functions.